# Capturing photo through webcam and save it in local computer using JMF

Tags: jmf

I want to write jmf code for capturing the image through web cam at predefined interval and save it in my computer. if you have any idea , please suggest to me with example ,,,,,,,,

thanks

Comment: This is the same as your other recent question, isn't it ?

Comment: Sounds like anti-theft mechanism :)

Answer (score 0):

had the same idea and was thinking about writing some program to do that. if you are using windows machine there's a power toy utility which does snapshots using web cam. just schedule this utility with windows scheduller and you'll be having at least a mockup of the system. if it doesn't fulfill your needs write your own implementation